# Best statistical methods for assessing change in density

Tags: hypothesis-testing, repeated-measures

I am measuring the change in density of algae over time. I have seven different species and I am testing their different ability to survive after treatment compared to control. I made 7 control samples for each - and seven treated samples (no replicates). The treatment is the only variable - all physical and chemical conditions were held constant.

[image: data set example]

Because each was grown in a different tube the density of the algae at the starting point was different on day 1 before adding treatment. I tried indexing my data to a common starting point by using percent change.

I was wondering if there any other methods I can use that are more accurate?

Comment: What do you mean by "density"? What are these numbers? Are they counts of colonies, eg?

Comment: it's a fluorescence measurement that can reflect how much algae is in the tube.

Answer (score 0):

you have your linear term which is Date which is change over time, but the Date squared term will give you the rate of change over time.